# Twitter Bootstrap Popovers and Tooltips on Listbox Option Elements showing in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

I have setup a quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmccord/6gezu/2/) to demonstrate the problem.

When using either a tooltip or a popover from Bootstrap on an option element of a select list, the popover or tooltip doesn't show next to the item, but rather in the extreme upper left of the page.

The HTML I am using is:

```html
<select size="5" id="testList">
    <option value="1" rel="popover" data-original-title="This is item 1." data-content="Lots of stuff to say" style="color: red; ">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2" rel="popover" data-original-title="This is item 2." data-content="Lots of stuff to say" style="color: green; ">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3" rel="popover" data-original-title="This is item 3." data-content="Lots of stuff to say" style="">Item 3</option>
    <option value="4" rel="popover" data-original-title="Blah" data-content="Lots of stuff to say" style="color: orange; ">Item 4</option>
</select>​
```

The javascript call is simple:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#testList option[rel=popover]').popover({
        placement: 'right',
        trigger: 'hover'
    });
});  ​
```

What can I do to make it show up in the right place?

Comment: Interestingly, the jsFiddle linked appears to be working now.  Perhaps a newer version has fixed this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is expected. TB `tooltip` / `popover` calculates their position based on the associated elements `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`. Option does not have such properties, never has, so a `popover` will always end up in something relative to the farmost `body` left/top.

**However**, you can place a popover for the `select` itself. Bind `mouseover` for the select, from that show a popover to the right populated with data attributes for the `option` being hovered.

HTML, cleaned for `rel="popover"` and `"data-original-title"`

```html
<select size="4" id="testList">
<option value="1" data-title="This is item 1." data-content="Lots of stuff to say 1" style="color:red;">Item 1</option>
<option value="2" data-title="This is item 2." data-content="Lots of stuff to say 2" style="color:green;">Item 2</option>
<option value="3" data-title="This is item 3." data-content="Lots of stuff to say 3" style="">Item 3</option>
<option value="4" data-title="Blah" data-content="Lots of stuff to say 4" style="color:orange;">Item 4</option>
</select>​​
```

bind mouseover, collect option data-attribues, show popover

```js
$("#testList").on('mouseover', function(e) {
    var $e = $(e.target); 
    if ($e.is('option')) {
        $('#testList').popover('destroy');
        $("#testList").popover({
            trigger: 'manual',
            placement: 'right',
            title: $e.attr("data-title"),
            content: $e.attr("data-content")
        }).popover('show');
    }
});
```

some cleanup so the popover disappears when we leave the select

```js
$("#testList").on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('#testList').popover('destroy');
});
```

doesnt think it can be done much better for an option list :) You *could* struggle with `template`, forcing the popover to more or less follow the vertical position for each option by its index.

forked code **http://jsfiddle.net/mM8sx/**

---

**Update** - issues with IE and Chrome on windows.
I have seen some references to this answer, pointing out that it was not working in IE and Chrome on windows. It is due to the fact that on windows, `<option>` elements doesnt receive mouse events at all. Here is a "hack" of the above answer, making it "crossbrowser".

Sucesssfully tested with Chrome, FF, IE and Safari on Windows. Chrome, FF and Opera on Ubuntu. The idea is to target the correct `<option>` on mousemove (not mouseover) by calculating the index based on the mouseevents `clientY` / height of a option.

```
$("#testList").on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (!isWindows) {
        var $e = $(e.target);
    } else {
        var newIndex = Math.floor(e.clientY/optionHeight);
        if (newIndex === index) return;
        index = newIndex;
        $e = $(this).find('option:eq('+index+')');
    }    
    if ($e.is('option')) {
        $('#testList').popover('destroy');
        $("#testList").popover({
            trigger: 'manual',
            placement: 'right',
            title: $e.attr("data-title"),
            content: $e.attr("data-content")
        }).popover('show');
    }
});
```

see fiddle for details -> **http://jsfiddle.net/LfrPs/**

Comment: Your fiddle works as intended, but I had a followup question. What if I didn't want to explicitly set the size of the select? How then could I still get the popover with a dropdown select element?

Comment: @Sam, would love to solve this - unfortunately the `mouseover` event for `option` is not triggered when `size` is not set. It works in FireFox, but not in Chrome or Opera (havent tested IE), so you cant determine which popover that needs to be displayed.

Comment: Great ideas, but the 'mousemove' version doesn't work reliably now in Firefox, and the other ones don't work at all with version 3.x of Bootstrap, in my testing. :(

Answer (score 2):

Tried very hard to apply the same popover box to a drop-down box without luck :

1. It looks like there's no event fires at all for option elements within a drop down select.
2. The e.target of the hover event on a 'select' element will always be the select element itself ! There's no way you can get a reference to the 'option' tag that is being hovered.
3. I've also tried wrapping the text in a 'option' element into a 'span' element and try to add a 'hover' or 'mouseover' event listener to that 'span' element. This does not work either.

When change the drop down into a list, (i.e. adding size="xx" attribute ), option elements can then work as normal elements.  I suspect in a drop down boxes, all options are wrapped by the browser into a separated layer. No interaction with the inner elements of a select element is allowed. Please tell me if I am wrong.