# Bootstrap Popovers and Tooltips on dropdown list's option element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover, html-select

Inspired by the following discussion on [Twitter Bootstrap Popovers and Tooltips on Listbox Option Elements showing in the wrong place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126144/twitter-bootstrap-popovers-and-tooltips-on-listbox-option-elements-showing-in-th) and following on, I wanted to use the technique showed in the answer and use it on a simple dropdown list ie. a `select` element with no `size` attribute or `size="1"`.

While it continues to work on latest to date version of Firefox (V18), it doesn't anymore on Webkit based browsers (Chrome V24 nor Safari V6) on MacOS X as well as Windows 7.

Is there any way to make it work in Chrome as well as Safari?

Forked demo code is as http://jsfiddle.net/ryZ9q/

Comment: I dont think it is possible. Have really tried, the dropdown of a `<select>` with no size or `size=1` seems not to get _any_ mouseevents at all, in any browser. I would consider mimicking a `<select>` with some `<ul><li>..</ul>`. However, have made an addendum to the answer you are refering to above, so that it least works on the major browsers and on windows.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/11367256/136717.    I've updated your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/k8h5ofza/1/.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display a tooltip on an HTML "option" tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249591/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-on-an-html-option-tag)