# Add custom attributes to <select> options generated with Angular's ng-options

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, tooltip

[With Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips), you can very nicely [define tooltips for `<select>` options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13129651/441662) (stackoverflow.com), while Angular can conveniently generate and bind options with the [ngOptions](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select) attribute on a `<select>` element.

However, how can I add attributes to these generated `option` elements that can then be used by Bootstrap's tooltip plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/select.js) of AngularJS in its current version (1.0.4 and 1.1.2) it is not possible as `option` elements are created inside JavaScript code without possibility to specify any additional attributes.